# Mystery kitchen device with three finger loops, one attached to a sliding rod that passes through a ring

Tags: equipment

This is an oddball question but I am hoping someone can help me identify this device, which appears intended for use in a kitchen based on its location in a drawer full of other kitchen tools. As you can see it is about 4 inches long.

[image: mystery kitchen device]

Comment: Always reread "Doodad" by Ray Bradbury when given a box full of mystery kitchen tools.

Comment: Or watch [Dead Ringers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gdgkfIZdN0&feature=youtu.be&t=43)...

Comment: Wow - your tape measure doesn't have cm on it!  Is it normal to only have 1 measurement system on them where you are?

Comment: I would prefer a banana for scale.

Comment: One scale is normal in the U.S. for construction tape measures.

Comment: Doodad can be found [on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v32n01_1943-09_Firebelly).

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This is a [cherry pitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_pitter). The metal ring holds the cherry while the piston forces the pit out right through the cherry.

Comment: Doh! Of course it is. :)  Actually I never saw one of these before but now that you describe its function it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not that familiar to most people nowadays since most use cherry pie filling or buy canned pitted sour cherries. It works well but I remember how sore and tired my hand was after pitting enough cherries for a pie!

Comment: @Jude - Out of curiosity does the cherry have to be in a specific orientation for this device to work or can you just drop one in any-which-way?

Comment: It'll probably work best if it's oriented so that the plunger is going through where the stem was, @O.M.Y., although up or down doesn't matter.

Comment: I was considering modifying the barrel & hopper of an old paintball gun and adding a cam-driven "plunger" to push out the pit to make an automated one of these. Not sure how I would eject the empty cherry, yet.

Comment: Cherry-rigged solutions ... and why do they always put two non-pitted cherries in every jar of pitted ones?

Comment: @O.M.Y. : while I'm all for tinkering, be aware that there exist electric cherry pitters as well :). There are also more elaborate and larger ones, with a more ergonomic plunger, that you might easier to adapt automation-wise.

Comment: Wow, it's a very *old-school* cherry pitter! Newer single-cherry, manual pitters are often shaped more like paper staplers and are much easier on the hands. I was gifted a no-name knockoff of [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Dalla-Piazza-Lustro-Cherry-Pitter/dp/B000J1DP2A/ref=sr_1_327?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1493056032&sr=1-327&keywords=cherry+pitter) and it's quite nice to use.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_pitter

Answer (score 17):

Also seen to be used as an olive pitter.  Same solution, similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

Cherry or olive pitter: first two fingers trough the side loops, thumb through the center loop, raise the plunger and insert the fruit pole to pole at the bottom and depress the plunger